# How to map dynamic form table to model with JSP/Servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, mapping

The main problem is that the use of jsp and servlets are required. In the table below, there is the opportunity to dynamic add and remove rows. Each row is an user task. How can i map these table of task to a List oft tasks only with JSP and Servlets? (List)

[image: form table example]

Comment: i tried to pass the data with jquery to servlet. the servlet build up the model. but iam not shure if that is the common way to do that